# Some of the pending updates cannot be applied because their dependencies were not met

Tags: updating

I have a Drupal 7 site that is giving me the above error.  I cannot for the life of me, figure out what dependency needs to be met.  And I can't not remember what I did, or if I did anything, to cause it.

Is there any way to get more info than that?

Comment: Which modules are the pending updates to be applied to?

Comment: That's the problem.  I can't see that info anywhere.  I don't know.  Is there a way to find out?  The watchdog says nothing.

Answer (score 2):

For those who end up here with the same issue on a Drupal 8 web site, I found that using drush's updb command will give information that the UI does not:

```
 drush updb
 [warning] The following module is missing from the file system: media_bulk_upload bootstrap.inc:276
 [warning] The following module is missing from the file system: media_upload bootstrap.inc:276
```

Comment: I have this issue on a D8.8.1 site and drush updb says only: success - no pending updates

Answer (score 1):

This may help: http://drupal.org/node/915216

Others that are more module specific may be:

1. http://drupal.org/node/1190294
2. http://drupal.org/node/1111524